# How do you configure Tracker search indexing tool?

Tags: gnome, search, tracker

The [project page](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/Tracker) mentions `tracker-preferences` but I don't have this command with version `2.0.3`.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The command `tracker-preferences` is from the [`tracker-gui` package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=tracker-gui), but the package is not available for Ubuntu 17.10 Artful Aardvark. In fact in Artful, tracker is not installed by default.

For other supported versions (Trust and Xenial) You may have to install the `tracker-gui` package first in order to run `tracker-preferences`.

Answer (score 9):

**Ubuntu 20.04**

Folders to include in scan can be specified in:

Settings → *Search* → *Search Locations* (button on top bar)

[image: Settings - Search - Search Location]

Also you can **exclude** a specific folder and its subfolders by creating an empty `.trackerignore` file in the folder.

Answer (score 6):

## Update for Ubuntu 20.04

In Ubuntu 20.04 and 19.10, the package `tracker-preferences` is not available. To configure what folders and files Tracker indexes, as well as other settings such as indexing while on battery:

- Install dconf Editor, either in Terminal via `sudo apt install -y dconf-editor` or in Ubuntu Software.
- Run dconf Editor (search for it in the desktop search).
- In dconf Editor, browse to org > freedesktop > Tracker > Miner > Files
- Carefully modify the settings for Tracker
- When you are done, simply close dconf Editor

Here is a screenshot of dconf Editor:
[image]

This can all me done via the command line as well via `gsettings`. To view the available settings, use:

```
gsettings list-recursively org.freedesktop.Tracker.Miner.Files
```

For more information on Tracker, read the useful but hard-to-find [Tracker FAQ](https://gnome.pages.gitlab.gnome.org/tracker/faq/).

Comment: For the record, this also applies to Ubuntu 22.04 "Jammy Jellyfish".