# Modifying file contents very slow on upgrade to Ubuntu 19.04

Tags: bash, upgrade, vim, tracker

I performed an upgrade from Ubuntu 18.10 to 19.04 and noticed that (somehow) creating, modifying, and deleting files is now much slower. Simply creating or deleting an empty file takes around 3 seconds on my relatively modern SSD.

Oddly enough, the commands themselves still run almost instantly:

```
$ time touch foo

real    0m0.003s
user    0m0.000s
sys     0m0.003s
```

Moreover, when I press the Enter key to execute the command, the cursor will stay on the same line during the 3 seconds. For these reasons I believe the issue is with Bash or the terminal hanging.

Similar behaviour can be seen when opening or saving files with Vim, except when running it in view mode.

EDIT
By request, I disabled all Gnome extensions, to no avail. The command `ls -al ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions` shows that the directory is empty.

Comment: Do you happen to be running one of the "Top Bar" gnome extensions?

Comment: @CharlesGreen I don't believe so. I had a media player extension but had to disable it since it is not support on Gnome 3.32. Removing the extension and restarting did not solve the problem.

Comment: and the `top` command does not show any processes consuming excess CPU time?

Comment: Very likely a GNOME extension problem. Go to https://extensions.gnome.org/local/ and temporarily disable ALL extensions, and either restart GNOME shell, or log out/in, and retest for slowness. Edit your question and show me `ls -al ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions`. Report back.

Comment: @CharlesGreen There's nothing taking up more than 1% CPU.

Comment: @heynnema Disabling all Gnome extensions unfortunately didn't help. I edited the question with the result of your command, which was that the directory is empty.

Comment: @DKBose Yes I did

Comment: Could it have something to do with file indexing/tracking?

Comment: @DKBose Thanks, that was exactly it. Disabling `tracker` solved the problem. If you post your comment as an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since your issue is related to creating or deleting files, it's possible that the system's indexing/tracking activity is responsible for the delays you see.

From the [release notes for Disco Dingo](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DiscoDingo/ReleaseNotes):

> Tracker is now included by default. This allows the desktop to keep
>   track of recently used files and improves searching.

A graphical interface present in early versions of *tracker* [has been removed in more recent versions](https://askubuntu.com/a/1012776/248158), but going into *Settings > Search* provides an on/off switch (**1** in the image below), as well as an interface to choose which folders are to be indexed (the little cog wheel icon next to **2** in the image below).

**Turning Tracker on/off or adjusting its settings**

[image: Tracker: System Settings > Search]

Alternatively, one can use the terminal:

`tracker --help` points to `tracker daemon` and `man tracker-daemon` points to `tracker daemon --kill` as well as other options.

When I ran `tracker daemon --kill`, I got:

```
dkb@dkb-UM:~$ tracker daemon --kill
Found 3 PIDs…
  Killed process 1486 — “tracker-miner-apps”
  Killed process 1494 — “tracker-miner-fs”
  Killed process 1496 — “tracker-store”
dkb@dkb-UM:~$ pgrep -al tracker
dkb@dkb-UM:~$
```

---

It's quite possible that *tracker* hogs a lot of resources in the short term just after upgrading from a system in which *tracker* was **not** in use to 19.04 where *tracker* is on by default.

I came across [Getting Started](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/Tracker/Documentation/GettingStarted) and [First 5 minutes with Tracker](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/Tracker/Documentation/First5Minutes) which are quite simple introductory articles on *tracker*. If one reads those articles, it should be possible to benefit from *tracker*.

Comment: Disabling `tracker` solved the issue.

Comment: @AlessandroPower Very interesting - I had not realized that a graphical interface has been re-implemented.  I had found somewhere that deleteing the `tracker` directories under `.cache` and `.local/share` also improved tracker performance - sometimes it runs across files that it cannot index properly.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem. Appears to be a bug in a gnome extension:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-shell-extension-desktop-icons/+bug/1826604

Rename the folder of desktop-icons extension solve my problem.