# Performance issues after upgrading to 19.04

Tags: upgrade, gnome-shell, performance, 19.04

I just upgraded from 18.10 to 19.04, and i am facing a tough drop in performance. Fan is spinning really high, and no smooth operation of the gnome-shell possible anymore. 
Sensors are showing this:

```
sensors
iwlwifi-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:        +34.0°C

thinkpad-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
fan1:        4437 RPM

acpitz-acpi-0
Adapter: ACPI interface
temp1:        +73.0°C  (crit = +128.0°C)

coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Package id 0:  +69.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 0:        +69.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 1:        +65.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)

pch_skylake-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:        +58.5°C
```

top showing this:

```
1785 sh        20   0  657676  49084  34348 S  15,6   0,2   0:55.10 gnome-system-mo
9759 sh        20   0 2761588 228272  86056 S  12,3   1,1   1:25.96 gnome-shell
9624 sh        20   0  407532 146820 127880 S   4,0   0,7   0:38.39 Xorg
```

with gnome-shell process continously going up to 95% and dropping again.

On 18.10 on gnome everything was fine. I am running a Lenovo T470s, 20GB of RAM, should not have any issues, should it?

Anyone facing a similar behaviour? Any idea of how to solve this / what is the reason for this?

Comment: Does running `tracker daemon --kill` help? If it does, please see https://askubuntu.com/a/1138233/248158.

Comment: Thx, that reduces that speed of the fan by 400RPM, so yes, it did definetly help, but my gnome-shell still behaves "laggy".

Comment: the situation is not really improving, still a lot of noise produced by the fan, and i can not point the cursor precisely because the machine is busy. Also, the tracker-process starts with every new terminal opened. Didn't find any settings in gsettings to disable it completely, is there?

Comment: You can turn off *tracker* completely via the GUI as shown in the link.

Comment: i disabled "Search" via the GUI completely, as shown in the linked question, but that does not prevent the three tracker process from starting up (even after a relogin) every time i fire up a new terminal

Comment: when i unplug my T470s from the Lenove USB-C-Dock, the temperature of the CPU drops by 30 degress,. the fan gets down to 0 RPM. 
wtf?

Comment: replugging the dock seems to not raise up that behaviour again, so it seems like, after finishing the upgrade to 19.04, you will have to replug your machine to the dock, in case you are using one (especially if it is the 40AC0135 from Lenovo)

Answer (score 2):

The answer was posted in comments:

> When I unplug my T470s from the Lenovo USB-C-Dock, the temperature of the CPU drops by 30 degrees. The fan gets down to 0 RPM.
>
> –  [hage](https://askubuntu.com/users/98240) on [Apr 30 '19 at 13:58](https://askubuntu.com/posts/comments/1888488)

> replugging the dock seems to not raise up that behaviour again, so it seems like, after finishing the upgrade to 19.04, you will have to replug your machine to the dock, in case you are using one (especially if it is the 40AC0135 from Lenovo)
>
> – [hage](https://askubuntu.com/users/98240) on [Apr 30 '19 at 15:16](https://askubuntu.com/posts/comments/1888548)