# After upgrading from 18.10 to 19.04, `tracker-extract` eats up so much RAM it freezes my machine

Tags: 19.04, tracker, indexing

I did `do-release-update` from 18.10 and my computer freeze after a couple minutes using gnome with the `tracker-extract` process, even though my computer has 8 Go of RAM and 4 Go of SWAP that all get fully used. I can log in and work with any other desktop environment and I won't have that problem. I found out that I can remove `tracker-extract` following the process described [here](https://gist.github.com/vancluever/d34b41eb77e6d077887c), which is what I'm going to do, even though I would have like to have that feature working.

Any pointers ?

Comment: You can use the Search GUI to restrict what is tracked. Then, once things settle down, allow more locations one by one? See https://askubuntu.com/a/1138233/248158

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Tracker was not enabled in 18.10. But, now, in 19.04, it's on by default.

If you've upgraded from 18.10 to 19.04, and you have a lot of files by such as documents, movies, music, photographs, videos etc. it's possible that tracker may take a long time to index everything. Until tracker's done, you may experience heavy resource usage.

I suggest that **immediately** after you login, open the *Settings > Search* interface, *leaving the topmost slider green* move the slider to the left for Ubuntu Software, Passwords …, and Terminal. Then click on the cog wheel and disable search for most of the items which you feel have the most files.

[image: Settings > Search GUI]

Now, hopefully, tracker should be able to complete it's job because you've limited its scope. If that indeed happens, go back to the *Settings > Search* interface and enable something else and so on.

---

Edit: as pointed out by [starkus in a comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1146074/after-upgrading-from-18-10-to-19-04-tracker-extract-eats-up-so-much-ram-it-fr/1146127?noredirect=1#comment1902650_1146127), it maybe necessary to reset tracker by clearing out the existing database in case it has developed some problem such as corruption:

tracker reset --hard

will do the job but please run `tracker --help reset` to read about it first.

Comment: @starkus thanks! I will add that to cover the possibility of the database being corrupt for whatever reason.

Comment: I did not try the answer yet, because I don't use gnome a lot and disabled tracker which solved the problem. Since the answer is well detailed and helped other people I assume it deserves to be accepted.