# How to install tracker-ui on ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: gnome, software-installation

How do i install `tracker-ui` on ubuntu 18.04 so that i can run `tracker-preferences` and load music to `gnome-music` as explained in this guide [here](https://superuser.com/questions/842289/how-to-refresh-gnome-music)

when i try to install i get:

```
sudo apt install tracker-ui     
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package tracker-ui
```

Comment: The `tracker` package was only available in 16.04 ("Xenial") and is no longer maintained. See https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/tracker/1.6.2-0ubuntu1.1 The author's Launchpad account has been deactivated.

Comment: And Ubuntu doesn't have a package called *tracker-ui*. What you read for other operating systems may not be applicable here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved the issue using **tracker**

`tracker daemon -t` *(terminate tracker daemons)*

then

`tracker daemon -s` *(start tracker daemons)*

`tracker status` *(check status)*

No need to install tracker-ui or tracker-gui

Comment: This might be how you solved your issue, but this is not the answer to your question "how to install tracker-ui"

Comment: In the first place, you need to answer your question as asked. Only then is it fine to add eventually alternative approaches or workarounds, i.e., in this case not related to tracker-ui. This site is aimed to collect expertise and information. It is not a user support forum.

Comment: Solved! Works for me!

Comment: It might not answer the shown question, but I want to add that this works very well for stopping trackers consuming noticeable amount of cpu.

Answer (score 2):

Tracker has been [re-introduced](https://askubuntu.com/a/1146127/248158) since 19.04. If you want to use it, upgrade or install Ubuntu 19.04.

Note that there is [no package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=default&section=all&arch=any&keywords=tracker-ui&searchon=names) called *tracker-ui* in the Ubuntu repositories.

As pointed out by [vanadium below](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1177638/how-to-install-tracker-ui-on-ubuntu-18-04/1177643?noredirect=1#comment1966654_1177643), *tracker* itself is available in Ubuntu 18.04 but without *tracker-gui*, not *tracker-ui*, which has been discontinued.

Comment: Tracker is also available in 18.04, but there is not used by Ubuntu by default. Tracker-ui, which the OP asks for, was a graphical tool to query tracker, and is not anymore available.

Comment: Thanks, I'll add that.

Comment: any workaround upgrading to ubuntu 19.04 is not an option for me.

Answer (score 1):

Likely, the name of the package should read `tracker-gui` rather than `tracker-ui`. No package with the latter name was ever in the Ubuntu repositories.

`tracker-gui` used to contain graphical applications to interact with the tracker database. It contained a search tool and `tracker-preferences`. The package `tracker-gui` was included in the Ubuntu repositories up to version 17.10. It apparently is not anymore maintained, and has been dropped from subsequent Ubuntu versions.

`tracker-gui` as such is not needed. You typically query tracker through Activities, or through any of the applications that can use (Files in 18.04) or require (Gnome Photo's, Gnome Documents) Tracker. You can to some extent control what is being searched in Gnome Setting - Search. Various settings are not exposed to the user, but can be changed using dconf-editor.

Comment: i meant `tracker-ui` as mentioned in the link i provided. Also `tracker` is installed in my ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: Most likely a spelling error in the link. Ubuntu had a package "tracker-gui", not "tracker-ui".

Comment: alright.... i did solve the issue though since tracker is installed `tracker daemon -t`  *(terminate tracker daemons)* then `tracker daemon -s` *(start tracker daemons)*  `tracker status` *(check status)*

Answer (score 0):

This package is only available on Ubuntu trusty, xenial and zesty, it is not available on 18.04, you should try the recoll package instead but you gonna have to adapt your guide with it.