# help! tracker-extract consumes my entire cpu and freezes my screen

Tags: freeze, 20.04, tracker

Hello is there any way to stop, remove or do something to the tracker process? It slows down my machine a lot and freezes it. I have Ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: See here to disable tracker all together: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1187191/tracker-process-taking-lot-of-cpu?rq=1, see https://askubuntu.com/questions/1146074/after-upgrading-from-18-10-to-19-04-tracker-extract-eats-up-so-much-ram-it-fr?rq=1 to limit the search scope of tracker and hence its activity