# Memory leak in tracker-extract?

Tags: nautilus, 19.04, tracker

Last night, my Ubuntu 19.04 suddenly became unresponsive, then on and off for a while. The fan started spinning rapidly, as a sign that much work was being done inside. I managed to start a system monitor, and the memory usage looked quite disturbing:

[image: Memory usage graph]

As you can see, my RAM filled up rapidly, invoking my swap partition, until both were full, at which point all memory seemed to be released, starting a new RAM-filling cycle.

I managed to reboot the machine, only to discover that the RAM eating started immediately again.

A `top` showed me that the offending process was `tracker-extract`, which I managed to uninstall, and after another reboot, no more RAM eating.

As it turned out, I had removed Nautilus in the process. `sudo apt install nautilus` installed tracker-extract again, but it has behaved itself since then.

Is this a known problem? Can I see somewhere what went wrong, so that I can prevent it from happening again?

Comment: See if https://askubuntu.com/a/1138233/248158 helps.

Comment: Disabling tracker via Settings GUI doesn't work. `tracker daemon --kill` works, but then I have to do it manually after every boot, after waiting for a couple of minutes for a terminal, since my system responds so slowly when tracker is running. Isn't there a way of disabling tracker altogether?

Answer (score 1):

I am also having this problem. When I extract a certain archive, tracker-extract will almost immediately fill up all RAM and swap. Upon reboot, it will do it again after a few seconds. Only solution is to boot in maintenance mode and delete the extracted folder. I don't know what file is causing it, so it's hard to file a bug report.

Answer (score 1):

After hours of frustration I just force removed the tracker package.

```
sudo dpkg --force-all -r tracker
```

Comment: Doesn't that also remove Nautilus?